# Bugs Verified or Bugs Validated?

Tags: manual-testing, terminology

Which sentence is correct.

Defects have been fixed and tested by QA. No issues found furthermore. So, what should QA has to write?

**Defect XXX has been verified. No issues found.**
OR
**Defect XXX has been validated. No issues found**

Comment: OK. Let us consider I have tested functionality against defect XXX. Then?

Comment: Verification: Verifying process includes checking documents, design, code and program.

Validation: It is a dynamic mechanism of testing and  validating the actual product.

According to definitions, I thinks correct sentence is bugs have been validated. No further issues found. But most people says, bugs have been verified. Any senior can help me?

Answer (score 5):

*Verification* answers the question:  "Are we building the product right?"  Does it conform to its specification?

*Validation* answers the question:  "Are we building the right product?"  Is it doing what the user really needs/wants?

To answer the question, it depends on the nature of the defect.

If you confirm the fixes for defect now allow the product to function as intended, you have *verified* the fixes.

If you confirm the fixes for the defect change the behavior to fulfill the intended usage, you have *validated* the fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Verified:

> Adj.  1.  verified - proved to be true; "a verified claim"

I think validated means the same, both are used for confirmations.

In this case the sentence should be:

> Defect XXX **fixes** have been verified.

Since its not the defect that is verified, that would mean it was reproduced, but you want to say it was resolved correctly.

Personally I would just set a company standard, it doesn't really matter what the terminology is, as-long everyone in your company understands what it means.

Maybe its better to ask on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Doesn't matter as long as everyone understands."  Right.  And if someone uses a term and you aren't sure what they mean, ask them what they mean.  That works a lot better than asking a bunch of strangers on SQA.

Comment: If your questions is about proper use of English: Instead of asking people here for many of which English is second language, and your English is second language too, ask on ELL (English Language Learners) exchange.

Comment: Good answer. I would write it as "The fixes for Defect XXX have been verified."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, QA doesn't (or rather can't) do anything on its own. Read the first sentence carefully, I've written: "its" and not his or her. Any guesses why?

Well QA (I'm assuming you mean Quality Assurance) is a process. Process doesn't do anything. Someone implements the process to get something done. You might want to Google it to learn more about the process.

And now to the question, I prefer to write "Issue has been resolved by " and then close the bug. This works well with my project team/stakeholders. What others write is totally up to them and their team's mutual understanding.

Happy Testing :)

Answer (score 1):

In general QA verifies an validates features and not defects so both the sentences could be misleading for your colleagues and the management. Why don't you simply write "**Defect XXX has been resolved.**"?

Answer (score 1):

In qa company, various defects have been verified by QA team. Both the terms are correct if the defect is working fine with no new issues.

But if the defect fix change the behavior of feature to fulfill the business requirement then we can use term "Defect XXX has been validated." along with the issues found during defect validation.

Comment: I agree. We are engineers we do not care about the sentence and philosofy. It is WORKING by. :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Verification has low-level activities like reviews, walkthroughs, inspections, and desk-checking.
- Validation needs high-level activities like black-box testing, white-box testing, and non-functional testing.

But in this case, it seems to be a bug fix that has been validated. It would be nice to say "Fix for defect XXX has been validated."

Answer (score 0):

Generally in cases where a defect has been tested and is found to be fixed , it is termed as Defect has been VALIDATED.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Defect Passed QA. There is no need to complicate things.

Comment: I feel this is too vague and could be misconstrued as "Defect past QA".  In my experience (1) Developers fix or resolve a defect (2) QA performs validations i.e. "expecting X value and X was found" and finally (3) QA has verified fix for defect #

Comment: Actualy it is the status of defect in sails force after the Qa performed testing and did not find any issues.No need for language playing or philozophy shifting.